# I write a Serach Bar Code,but that one run Perfectly on iPhone Devices but not on iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad

### iPad won't Display, what i want

when Click on search button, navigation bar's TitleView set as search bar
and display cancel button on front of search bar.
but in iPad cancel button not display this is my problem.

[This is the Actual result on All iPhone Device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pgh3P.png)

[But when I Execute With iPad,then code shows like this,cancel button is not display front of search bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMPq3.png)

### My Code is here

```
class MenuTableViewController: UITableViewController,UISearchBarDelegate{
//MARK: - Declare Variable

let searchBar = UISearchBar()
var image = UIImage()
var menuList:NSMutableArray = ["About Us","Packages","Locations","Hot News","Testimonials","FAQ's","Contact"]
let colorArray:[UIColor] = [UIColor.blackColor(),UIColor.blueColor(),UIColor.brownColor(),UIColor.cyanColor(),UIColor.purpleColor(),UIColor.greenColor(),UIColor.orangeColor()]

//MARK: - Outlet variable

//MARK: - Outlet Methods

//MARK: - ViewDidLoad
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true


    image = UIImage(named: "photo.png")!
    self.navigationItem.titleView = UIImageView(image: image)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Search, target: self, action:(#selector(MenuTableViewController.searchData)))
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "399-list1"), style: .Done, target: self, action: (#selector(MenuTableViewController.menuDisplay)))

    self.searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
    self.searchBar.delegate = self

}

//MRAK: - SerachBar Delegate Methods

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    print("Cancel")
    self.navigationItem.titleView = UIImageView(image: image)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Search, target: self, action:(#selector(MenuTableViewController.searchData)))
}

//MARK: - Search Methods
func searchData() {
    print("done search")
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
    // add the search bar (which will start out hidden).
    self.navigationItem.titleView = searchBar;
    searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
}

//MARK: - Menu Display Methods
func menuDisplay() {
    print("display menu")
}
```

Comment: It looks about the same... Seems like if you start editing your search controller then the cancel button will appear. It is stretched out on the iPad to fit the screen.

Comment: @penatheboss what is solution?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Could you explain what is going wrong?

Comment: when i click on search bar button on the left corner then  title view in the navigation bar is hide and search bar appear with cancel button. this works on iPhone but not on iPad. the iPad hide the cancel button. will you help me to do that, plz

Comment: @penatheboss - No, it's not same. on iPhone cancel button appear in front of search bar. but on iPad cancel button not appear.

Comment: Are you using the same code fore each scene?

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to solve your problem. Good luck in finding the right answer.